# Intution behind Caratheodory’s Criteria

Tags: measure-theory

Caratheodory’s Criteria says that $\mu$ is a Borel measure if $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A) + \mu(B)$ for all sets $A$ and $B$.

It surprises me because, then, $\mu(A\cap B)=0$ for all sets $A$ and $B$.

Does it mean that if a measure is Borel, all sets are disjoint? What is the intuition behind that?

Since the measure theory is abstract, I have difficulty understanding Borel measure.

Comment: What you called Caratheodory's criterion is not only not Caratheodory's criterion (as FisiaiLusia's answer points out), but it's false.  Where did you get it from?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear. reference : 3 page in  http://www.math.toronto.edu/~k3thomps/Documents/Geometric_Measure_Theory-Part_1(Feb2012).pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. Your question left out an essential part of (what is there called) Caratheodory's criterion, namely the assumption that $d(A,B)>0$, where $d$ is the metric on your space. So, returning to your question, it is certainly true (and trivial) that *if* $d(A,B)>0$ then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: Doesn't the Lebesgue measure hold? Whenever Borel measure appears in many texts, it seems not understandable to me.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the Lebesgue measure holding.

Answer (score 0):

Caratheodory condition says that if for all $E\subset X$ and some $A\subset X$ holds $$\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c)$$
then the set $A\subset X$ is called measurable in the sense of Caratheodory.